# Set CMSampleBuffer samples attachment (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, h.264

I'm trying to set the `kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately` for each of my samples in the `CMSampleBuffer`.

So far I've tried getting dictionaries (`Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>`, `NSDictionary`, `CFDictionary`), and invoked `CMSetAttachment` on both `CMSampleBuffer` and its attachments.

For retrieving attachments I use `CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray`.

Any ideas how can I set those flags in Swift?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the solution (probably far from perfect) that works with Swift 4 (should work with 3).

```
func setSampleBufferAttachments(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
    let attachments: CFArray! = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sampleBuffer, true)
    let dictionary = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachments, 0),
        to: CFMutableDictionary.self)
    let key = Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately).toOpaque()
    let value = Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCFBooleanTrue).toOpaque()
    CFDictionarySetValue(dictionary, key, value)
}
```